# How to delete two groups of characters with regex?

Tags: regex, ruby

I have this type of string:
**First part: [[archive 726|The Archive]] is a great start**

And I want to print:
**First part: The Archive is a great start**

Here is what I've come to far:

```
input.gsub!(/\[\[(.*?)\|/,"")
print input
> "First part: The Archive]] is a great start"
```

How can I also match the ]]?

Answer (score 3):

You may use

```
input.gsub!(/\[\[[^\]\[]*\|(.*?)\]\]/, '\1')
```

See the [Rubular demo](https://rubular.com/r/uSAqCgjNhPGs5D) and a [Ruby demo](https://ideone.com/TdYvxW).

**Details**

- `\[\[`  - a `[[` substring
- `[^\]\[]*` - any 0 or more chars other than `[` and `]`, as many as possible (if there are multiple `|` chars inside `[[...]]`, replace `*` with `*?` to match as few as possible)
- `\|` - a `|` char
- `(.*?)` - Group 1 (the group value is referred to with `\1` from the replacement pattern, mind the single quotes around `\1`): any 0 or more chars other than line break chars, as few as possible
- `\]\]` - a `]]` substring.